# If $A$ Is invertible $n\times n$ matrix which is made of only 1's and -1's, then $|\det(A)| \geq 2^{n-1}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

How do I prove what's written in the title (By saying "made of 1's and -1's" I mean that A contains only the numbers 1 and -1)? I tried using gauss elimination but I don't see how it helps me, and I have no other idea. If any of you could help me or at least give me a hint, It will help me a lot. Thanks!

Comment: I think you want $\;|\det A|\;$ , with absolute value, otherwise the claim is false.

Comment: @DonAntonio Yep. You are right, my bad. Editing.

Comment: Fun fact: it’s also true that $|\det(A)|\le n2^{n-2}$ when $n\ge 2$.

Comment: @SantanaAfton Each row has norm $\sqrt{n}$.  If rows are orthogonal, which gives maximum absolute value of the determinant, then $\lvert\det(A)\rvert=n^{n/2}$, which can be much greater than $n2^{n-2}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Gaussian elimination is definitely (one of) the right way(s) to go. Think about what happens when you've gotten your matrix into upper-triangular form. Can you get $n-1$ factors of $2$ to pop out anywhere and still get the determinant of an integer matrix? Here's a (simple) example:

$$\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 & 1 \end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & -2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 2 \end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & -2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 \end{vmatrix}=2^2\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{vmatrix}.$$

Comment: I think you gave me an idea. detA is not 0, since otherwise, A would not be invertible. Let's name the rows of A: R_1,R_2,...,R_n. We'll do the following:                             R_2-->R_2-R_1,R_3-->R_3-R_1,...,R_n-->R_n-R_1. The determinant hasn't changed. Look at the new rows R_1,...,R_n. None of them is all 0's, otherwise detA=0. but each element in them is one of the following sums: 1+(-1), 1+1, (-1)+(-1). So It's 0,2 or -2. So we can factor out 2 out of each of those rows (n-1 factors of 2) and still get an integer matrix, whose determinant is not 0. so we are done. ?

Comment: can you or someone else verify it's right (sorry for not editing and double-commenting, I can't edit, not sure why (maybe I edited too many times?)

Comment: @Omer yes, you even further simplified the answer, since we don't need to go into the upper-triangular form.

Comment: @PetiteEtincelle Okay. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ be a matrix with entries $\pm 1$ of size $n>1$. The case $n=1$ is immediate.
We are going to transform $A$ in two steps, without altering
$\,|\!\det A|\,$:

**(1)** Take the first column and the first row of $A$ to define diagonal matrices
$C=a_{11}\cdot\operatorname{diag}(a_{11},-a_{21},\dots,-a_{n1})\:$ and 
$\:R=\operatorname{diag}(a_{11},a_{12},\dots,a_{1n})\,$.
Then $|\!\det C|=|\!\det R|=1$, and multiplying $A$ from the left and the right yields
$$CAR\;=\;\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&\cdots &1\\ -1\\ \vdots &&B\\ -1  
\end{pmatrix}$$
where $B\,$ is a submatrix of size $n-1$ with entries from {$\pm 1\}$.

**(2)** Now let's add the first row in the $CAR\,$ to all the other rows to obtain
$$\begin{vmatrix}
1&1&\cdots &1\\ -1\\ \vdots &&B\\ -1  
\end{vmatrix}
\quad=\quad
\begin{vmatrix}
1&1&\cdots &1\\ 0\\ \vdots &&2\cdot B'\\ 0  
\end{vmatrix}$$
and $B'$ has entries in $\{1,0\}$. Furthermore, $B'$ is singular iff $A$ is singular (also true if $n=2$).

Reaping the fruit of the preceding steps one has
$$\begin{align}|\!\det A|&\;=\;|\!\det(CAR)|\;=\;2^{n-1}\,|\!\det B'|\\[2ex]
&\;\geqslant\;2^{n-1},\end{align}$$
as claimed for non-singular $A$.